# Remove unwanted network fm iPhone

Tags: network

I have to delete fm iPhone memory 2 network names and settings, not removed by “forget this network” how can I ?i

Answer (score 1):

You can't. With iOS 10.x and iOS 11.0 it's possible to delete a Wi-Fi network

- if you can see it (Settings > Wi-FI)
- with all other saved Wi-Fi networks using Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings

You can't remove a specific Wi-Fi network otherwise.

If you have iCloud enabled you may want to sign in from another Mac and open Keychain Access.app. There you will see all Wi-Fi networks that were synced to iCloud. Delete it on the Mac with your iPhone still signed in to iCloud and restart your iPhone after about 5 minutes.